# How do I generate addends for a given sum using Python?

Tags: python, recursion, tree, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to generate the possible addends for any number between 0 and 30. The number of addends = 10, lower addend limit = 0, and upper addend limit = 3.

For example, for the number 30, the addends can be 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 30.

For 12, the addends can be, 3 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 12, or 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 12 or anything within the given limit. But the number of addends should always be 10.

Comment: A few things: 1. Proveread your question. 2. Stackoverflow is not there to do your homework. Try something, and we will help you get it to work. 3. Google is your friend. Stackoverflow is not a more complex google. Do your own research, there are dozens of pages and websites and examples for algorithms for this kind of problem.

Comment: Ok, how do I approach this problem? I can generate random numbers between the given limit using random.randint(0,3). I'm struggling with generating random addends. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Do you want to generate all of them or just any sequence that sums up to N? Easiest would be just as many 3's as you can, followed be N - however many 3's you have followed by 0's until you have N.

Comment: Thank you. I want to generate any sequence with 10 addends that sums up to numbers between 0 and 30. For example, if I want to generate a 10 addend sequence for the SUM 1,my sequence should be 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1. Samuel Duraivel

Answer (score 0):

Recursively create a tree with a branch for each of your possible values between the lower and upper limits (so in your case each branch with have 4 leaves for each of `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Your recursion base cases are that you're either deeper than levels 10 into the tree or that you've got the sum you want (in which case return it) or you've exceeded the sum (in which case return nothing). Assuming the order is significant (i.e. `3+1` is a distinct answer from `1+3`), that's it. I don't have time to code it for you.

Or, since you're working with small numbers, you can just brute force it by generating all 1,048,576 ways to chose 10 elements from `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and check which ones sum to what you want

```
from itertools import product

def addend_all(n):
    for combination in product(range(4), repeat=10):
        if sum(combination) == n:
            yield combination

for i in range(31):
    print(list(addend_all(i)))
```